# Kotlin smart cast the second value of a pair with filter

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write a function that maps a String and Int? into a pair, then filters for non null second values in the pair, before continuing to map.

My code looks like this:

```
val ids: List<String> = listOf("a", "b", "c")
val ints: Map<String, Int?> = mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2, "c" to null)

ids.map { id: String ->
    Pair(id, ints[id])
}.filter { pair -> pair.second != null}.map { pair: Pair<String, Int> ->
    func(id, pair.second)  
}
```

The problem is that the second map has the error:

```
Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in 
                       inline fun <T, R> kotlin.collections.Iterable<T>.map ( transform (T) -> R ): kotlin.collections.List<R>
```

This looks like because the compiler does not know to smart cast my `Iterable<Pair<String, Int?>>` into an `Iterable<Pair<String, Int>>` after my `filter`. What can I do instead to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin's smart cast is usually not applicable outside method boundaries. However, there are a couple of ways you can achieve your goal anyway.

First, you can simply tell the compiler that the second value of the pair is never null by using the `!!` operator like so:

```
ids.map { id: String -> Pair(id, ints[id]) }
        .filter { pair -> pair.second != null }
        .map { pair: Pair<String, Int?> -> func(pair.second!!) }
```

Second, you can reverse the order of `filter` and `map` and apply the `!!` operator earlier:

```
ids.filter { id: String -> ints[id] != null }
        .map { id: String -> id to ints[id]!! } //equivalent to Pair(id, ints[id]!!)
        .map { pair: Pair<String, Int> -> func(pair.second) }
```

Finally, you can make it work without the `!!` operator by combining the filtering and the mapping in one step using the `mapNotNull` extension method:

```
ids.mapNotNull { id: String -> ints[id]?.let { id to it } }
        .map { pair: Pair<String, Int> -> func(pair.second) }
```