# Why doesn't filter method do a smart-cast on the object in the subsequent method in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

This is just a sample code I wrote. The below is the data class for the Comment object.

```
data class Comment(
    val id: Int,
    val text: String?
)
```

And I'm performing a filter operation on a list of Comment objects.

```
commentList.filter { comment -> comment.text != null }
    .map { comment -> comment.text.length }
```

This leads to the compiler error on comment.text stating `Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver`. So my question is why doesn't the filter method, do a smart-cast on the text object and convert it into a non-nullable String type?

Also is there a better way where smart-casting is possible?

p.s. I know that I can always do this, but just out of curiosity would like to know if there is some default Kotlin extension function which can get the job done.

```
commentList.filter { comment -> comment.text != null }
    .map { comment -> comment.text?.let { text ->
             text.length
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with,

```
...?.let { text ->
         text.length
    }
```

can be simplified to

```
...?.length
```

I'd further combine `filter` and `map` using `mapNotNull`:

```
commentList.mapNotNull { comment -> comment.text?.length }
```

It could have different result from your original code if `length` could be `null` on a non-`null` input, but it can't.

Comment: Better than my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62751183/2356570

Answer (score 1):

It's because smart cast works within a method boundary.
`filter()` and `map()` are 2 different methods.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36568115/3486601) for a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment and the answer I got here, I can understand that smart-casts works only within a method boundary.

Alternatively I was able to find a different solution, which makes the code a bit elegant to my eyes.

```
    commentList.mapNotNull { comment -> comment.text }
        .map { text -> text.length }
```